# translating simple curl call to python/django request

Tags: python, django

I'm attempting to translate the following curl request to something that will run in django.

```
curl -X POST https://api.lemlist.com/api/hooks --data '{"targetUrl":"https://example.com/lemlist-hook"}' --header "Content-Type: application/json" --user ":1234567980abcedf"
```

I've run this in git bash and it returns the expected response.

What I have in my django project is the following:

```
        apikey = '1234567980abcedf'
        hookurl = 'https://example.com/lemlist-hook'
        data = '{"targetUrl":hookurl}'

        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        response = requests.post(f'https://api.lemlist.com/api/hooks/', data=data, headers=headers, auth=('', apikey))
```

Running this python code returns this as a json response

```
{}
```

Any thoughts on where there might be a problem in my code?

Thanks!

Comment: In data you are not passing the hookurl var you are just inputing the string, you probably wanted to do this f"targetUrl:{hookurl}"

Comment: Sorry, just to confirm, should it be data = f"targetUrl:{hookurl}"

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what nikoola said, I think you want that whole data line to be as follows so you aren't passing that whole thing as a string. Requests will handle serializing and converting python objects to json for you [EDIT: if you use the json argument instead of data].

source: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests

> Instead of encoding the dict yourself, you can also pass it directly
> using the json parameter (added in version 2.4.2) and it will be
> encoded automatically:
>
> Note, the json parameter is ignored if either data or files is passed.
>
> Using the json parameter in the request will change the Content-Type
> in the header to application/json.

```
data = {"targetUrl":hookurl}
```

Comment: I tried removing the quotes around this as you've suggested and the result appears to be the same.

Comment: print your reponse.text and see if there is a message for you. Are you using reponse.json() currently for the response?

Comment: ... and flip that call to `response = requests.post(f'https://api.lemlist.com/api/hooks/', json=data, headers=headers, auth=('', apikey))` and I think you can drop the headers as well in that case.

Comment: see the last example in this section: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests

Answer (score 0):

import requests

headers = {
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

data = '{"targetUrl":"https://example.com/lemlist-hook"}'

response = requests.post('https://api.lemlist.com/api/hooks', headers=headers, data=data, auth=('', '1234567980abcedf'))

You can visit this url:-
https://curl.trillworks.com/